# processing a datetime + timezone inputs into UTC with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

Ruby and rails have many methods to parse datetimes with timezone information, but lack an integrated mechanisms AFAIK to input both simultaneously, which is then compounded by the parsing requirements.

An application saves timestamps in UTC format, a birth date will have a timezone component
and another attribute to provide the offset for the time zone.

```
    t.timestamptz "birth_date"
    t.string "birth_date_tz"
```

The problem is handling the parameters properly.  The user is not thinking in UTC terms, but in the clock at the given time zone.

Thus, the following parameters need to first be offset to be translated into UTC

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "individual"=>{"birth_date(3i)"=>"1",  
"birth_date(2i)"=>"1", "birth_date(1i)"=>"1987", "birth_date(4i)"=>"01",  
"birth_date(5i)"=>"01", "birth_date_tz"=>"Hawaii",, "birth_location_city"=>"Honolulu"}
```

and would like to avoid saving, then updating.

How should these be processed?

*(later they will be viewed, retranslated for the offset of the tz)*

Comment: A birth date has no time zone.  It is just a date (year, month, day).  The location and time of birth are not relevant to a person's "age" in the way that it is typically calculated.  The only time zone of importance when calculating age is the one where a person is physically located at that time - as that determines what the person's idea of the _current_ date is.

Comment: In other words, `timestamptz` is an inappropriate database type for a birth date.  In most databases, the correct type is simply `date`, and it should not be converted to/from UTC.

Comment: I should caveat my previous comment - if you are trying to determine how many _years_ old a person is, then time and time zone of birth is not relevant.  However, they are indeed relevant if you are trying to calculate how many _minutes_ old a person is (such as for astrology purposes, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, obviously the app can't know what timezone is in the user's mind as they input their data, and although you can detect the **offset** of their current browser time in Javascript, you can't reliably translate that into a timezone anyway.

So yeah, after you do your assignment just:

```rb
individual.birth_date.change zone: individual_params[:birth_date_tz]
```

FWIW, all that being said a birth date doesn't actually have a timezone. If you're born just after midnight in New York your birthdate isn't the day before when you're in California.